# Intercepting encrypted SOAP message with SoapUI

Tags: encryption, soapui, ws-security

I try to intercept encrypted soap message with SoapUI. The reference site of WS Security with Wildfly 8 and Eclipse IDE is

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/WS-Security#WS-Security-Authenticationandauthorization

WS Security implementation is successful and the response message is encrypted successfully. The main key in WS security is manifest.mf. I add the following lines in manifest.mf file and it works well in Eclipse IDE.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.apache.cxf.impl, org.apache.ws.security services
Class-Path:
```

But in SoapUI application soap message encryption is failed. Me reference site is

http://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/ws-security.html

http://blog.thilinamb.com/2011/02/invoking-secured-web-service-with.html

The SEI throws the following exception.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}ProtectionToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EndorsingSupportingTokens: The received token does not match the endorsing supporting token requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EncryptedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not ENCRYPTED
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not SIGNED</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The same exception was thrown in Eclipse IDE when I did not add the Dependancies line in manifest.mf file. Do you think those are related and have the same configuration problem?